# Can I use phonegap childbrowwer plugin for android to display iages/files under /data/data/{package-name}/files directory

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I want to display a childbrowser window  for my image which is under /data/data/{packagename}/files.It display "webpage not available " error.Any ways I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open my image file using path file:///data/data/packagename/etc/image as parameter .